# magento 2 Venia PWA does not accept connection

Tags: php, magento, progressive-web-apps, magento2, venia

I'm having some problems with magento 2 PWA
I have first installed magento 2 and it is working fine. After that I've installed PWA under magento 2 root,all commands seems to work fine, but when I louch "yarn run watch:venia" I have this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOTGJ.png) that seems good, but if I try to reach the path written I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZTox.png).

Tha path https://magentopoc.dvl.to is the path where I have magento, but the problem will be present also if I set another URL for PWA.

Can anybody help me on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the PWA application as a separate application from the Magento backend. Second, can't see in the picture if you are using the port in the address. Anyway it's hard to say what you might have a problem with. Details of your local environment are missing. Is it nginx or apache? Probably your local settings from apache/nginx are conflicting with watcher.